# Unable to download files with drive api

Tags: office365, onedrive

Over the past 2 weeks, I've been seeing an increasing number of files that I am unable to download when using the drive api.

It appears that the server is cutting off the connection during the download.

Here is an example:

```
GET https://fakeurl-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F
```

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://myname-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_api/v2.0/$metadata#items/$entity",
    "@odata.type": "#oneDrive.item",
    "@odata.id": "https://fake-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F",
    "@odata.editLink": "drive/items/01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F",
    "@content.downloadUrl": "https://fake-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=03df4267-9112-4aba-ae2b-28c803a53765&Translate=false&tempauth=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJub25lIn0.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.WHBCc0RvdC9aOS9rcHRWNXBMYUlVYWxvVHVTRFlORFZ3aDJjcnRFYmR4OD0&ApiVersion=2.0",
    "createdBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "myname@fake.com",
            "id": "b9006b02-228f-481b-a0c1-xxxxxxxxx",
            "displayName": "Fake Name"
        }
    },
    "createdDateTime": "2017-12-01T13:50:33Z",
    "eTag": "\"{03DF4267-9112-4ABA-AE2B-28C803A53765},1\"",
    "id": "01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F",
    "lastModifiedBy": {
        "user": {
            "email": "myname@fake.com",
            "id": "b9006b02-228f-481b-a0c1-7b1cc6802435",
            "displayName": "Fake User"
        }
    },
    "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-12-01T13:50:33Z",
    "name": "Open Notebook.onetoc2",
    "parentReference": {
        "driveId": "b!oikuy7ZnXU6-MAFzRbCNu1ZsW-M5LqtEiTgGcmCLDPH87jfUKtlDT69Imd4dxRTq",
        "driveType": "business",
        "id": "01ECRXEPNFSYWD4HTYDRHIHHGKT3DX3MDB",
        "path": "/drive/root:/Test sync to PC/OneNote_RecycleBin"
    },
    "webUrl": "https://fake-my.sharepoint.com/personal/mynae_fake_com/_layouts/WopiFrame.aspx?sourcedoc=%7B03DF4267-9112-4ABA-AE2B-28C803A53765%7D&file=Open%20Notebook.onetoc2&action=default",
    "cTag": "\"c:{03DF4267-9112-4ABA-AE2B-28C803A53765},1\"",
    "file": {
        "mimeType": "application/octet-stream"
    },
    "fileSystemInfo": {
        "createdDateTime": "2017-12-01T13:50:33Z",
        "lastModifiedDateTime": "2017-12-01T13:50:33Z"
    },
    "size": 2565
}
```

That proves the file exists.   Now I want to retrieve it.

```
curl -L -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer JWTTOKEN' https://fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F/content


*   Trying 13.107.6.151...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com (13.107.6.151) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* Server certificate: *.sharepoint.com
* Server certificate: Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
* Server certificate: Baltimore CyberTrust Root
> GET /personal/myname_fake_com/_api/v2.0/drive/items/01ECRXEPLHILPQGEURXJFK4KZIZAB2KN3F/content HTTP/1.1
> Host: fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer JWTTOKEN



< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
< Content-Type: application/octet-stream
< Expires: Thu, 21 Dec 2017 14:41:58 GMT
< Last-Modified: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 14:41:58 GMT
< Location: https://fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=03df4267-9112-4aba-ae2b-28c803a53765&Translate=false&tempauth=atempauthtoken&ApiVersion=2.0
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
< X-SP-SERVERSTATE: ReadOnly=0
< ODATA-VERSION: 4.0
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< Content-Disposition: attachment
< SPClientServiceRequestDuration: 81
< SPRequestDuration: 122
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< SPRequestGuid: 258f3d9e-701b-5000-b449-3a3e4a026425
< request-id: 258f3d9e-701b-5000-b449-3a3e4a026425
< MS-CV: nj2PJRtwAFC0STo+SgJkJQ.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.7206
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: 3F1A8FB58A7748778CE50FDD02750504 Ref B: SN1EDGE0820 Ref C: 2018-01-05T14:41:58Z
< Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 14:41:58 GMT
< Content-Length: 0

<
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com/personal/myname_fake_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=03df4267-9112-4aba-ae2b-28c803a53765&Translate=false&tempauth=mytempauth&ApiVersion=2.0'

* Found bundle for host fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com: 0x7fcbd95034f0 [can pipeline]
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com
* Connected to fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com (13.107.6.151) port 443 (#0)
> GET /personal/myname_fake_com/_layouts/15/download.aspx?UniqueId=03df4267-9112-4aba-ae2b-28c803a53765&Translate=false&tempauth=tempauthtoken&ApiVersion=2.0 HTTP/1.1
> Host: fakegroup-my.sharepoint.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Bearer JWTTOKEN
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Length: 2565
< Content-Type: application/onenote
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< ETag: "{03DF4267-9112-4ABA-AE2B-28C803A53765},1"
< P3P: CP="ALL IND DSP COR ADM CONo CUR CUSo IVAo IVDo PSA PSD TAI TELo OUR SAMo CNT COM INT NAV ONL PHY PRE PUR UNI"
< X-SharePointHealthScore: 0
< X-Download-Options: noopen
< Content-Disposition: attachment;filename*=utf-8''Open%20Notebook%2Eonetoc2;filename="Open Notebook.onetoc2"
< CTag: {03DF4267-9112-4ABA-AE2B-28C803A53765},1,1
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< SPRequestGuid: 258f3d9e-c022-5000-0fa4-018099cad340
< request-id: 258f3d9e-c022-5000-0fa4-018099cad340
< MS-CV: nj2PJSLAAFAPpAGAmcrTQA.0
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
< X-FRAME-OPTIONS: SAMEORIGIN
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices: 16.0.0.7206
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< X-MS-InvokeApp: 1; RequireReadOnly
< X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A: CB41267B6CF04447A4B8CE9E4E78312F Ref B: SN1EDGE0820 Ref C: 2018-01-05T14:41:58Z
< Date: Fri, 05 Jan 2018 14:41:58 GMT
<
�/�C��vL���W"v_�(���G�֢ȴ��G?ݚ�I����Ȯ����������ܮ��F���Q��+8jdk����������$`��������7f����O�ml�,������������zV�
��`<[G��_��K��<��Ӛ`��[G��_��K��<��Ӛ��������K�3������zV�

                                                       `��[G��_��K��<��Ӛ��������K�3��
* SSLRead() return error -9806
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 1
* Closing connection 0
curl: (56) SSLRead() return error -9806
```

So when the calling the /content api, we are issued a 302 that redirects to a download url with a temporary auth.  Is it possible the temporary auth is expiring prior to the download completing?

I consistently am getting the same results for this and have tried a variety of clients to retrieve the file (POSTMAN, curl, apache http).

Or, is this some type of regression with the infrastructure serving those files?

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be a bug with how `download.aspx` handles ghosted files. There isn't much you can do to work around the issue unfortunately, but thankfully the fix is pretty simple so we should hopefully have it resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty simple to handle this. When you try to download the file but get redirect response (*HTTP code 302*) retry your request. You can use `location` reply header value for this. Store this value somewhere. If you implement tool to download file programmatically then all calls need to have retry ability. Just take `location` reply header value obtained before and send new request using it. If you are just playing with api then you should simply resend the request using url value from `location` reply header.